# Core animation is not interactive when compiled with iOS 11 SDK

Tags: ios, animation

I have a `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition` based interactive transition similar to this effect:

[image: Effect]

There're two animations in my transition: one is the growing circle, with a `CABasicAnimation` on mask layer's path, which is a `CAShapeLayer`; another one is a UIView animation for alpha of the view.

Before iOS 11, it works well, however, when compiling with SDK of iOS 11 in Xcode 9, the animation of alpha works fine (interactive), while the path one is not interactive, meaning the animation is working but does not follow the pan gesture.

Then I tried animating opacity with `CABasicAnimation` it does not support interactive transition as well. I'm wondering if there's any broken changes causing `CABasicAnimation` not supporting `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition`?

**Update (2017-11-20):** temporarily, I refactored the animation to use maskView and its transform instead of CABasicAnimation on CALayer, it works fine now but still wondering why interactive CABasicAnimation is broken in iOS 11.